# Add View Outside of ContentView in Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell and I want to add a view to it. Apple states that views should be added to the `contentView`. This is there documentation:

> When configuring a cell, you add any custom views representing your cell’s content to this view. The cell object places the content in this view in front of any background views.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview

However, it seems I can also add view not inside the `contentView` and there is no warnings or crashes. Here is my code. Notice the comment `QUESTION` -- I want to know if this is ok to do:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var imageView: UIImageView!

    private let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // QUESTION: Is this ok? Notice I am not adding the `titleLabel` to `self.contentView`
        self.addSubview(titleLabel)

        let horizontalCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let verticalCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        self.addConstraint(horizontalCenterConstraint)
        self.addConstraint(verticalCenterConstraint)
    }
}
```

In the code above, instead of adding the view with `self.contentView.addSubview`... instead I simply do `self.addSubview`. Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

Most things are *possible*, The question is *why* do you want to do this?

By directly going against an API author's recommendation, you're risking a whole host of potential issues. e.g.

- You may be breaking something you're unaware of
- You may be adversely affecting performance
- Even if it works currently, it may break in the future and the author has no reason to prevent this from happening.

If what you're trying to do is impossible otherwise and you're ok with the risks, go for it. Otherwise, stick to the author's explicit instructions.

Comment: Ok, yeah I was unsure of Apple's documentation. Based on what you are saying, I should only add views to the cell's `contentView` correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried to add `cell` directly instead of `contentView`. Now, weird thing happens, the collection view could not scroll. It took me 1 hour to figure out that I should add itself to `contentView`